# After getting the child items for a specific folder I want to pass that as an input for another get-child item in a loop

Tags: powershell

I have 8 folders in a path..

I am able to pass as input each folder using foreach.

There are multiple folders in each folder of those 8 folders.

I need to get into at least four folders in each of 8 folders and need to get the last write time of the files in that folder,

Here is the sample code

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a528602\Desktop\Tools\Store Server\Servers.txt" 

Foreach($ServerName in $ServerList) 
{ 
    get-childitem $ServerName 
    $numberoffolders=(get-childitem).count
    #irrespective number of folders in the each folder I need to pick any four folders and get the last written time stamp
    for(I=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        $folder1 = get-childitem $ServerName   Need to get any one folder
        $folder1_time = ?
    }
}
```

can some one help in writing the powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

inside of your foreach loop using:

Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Directory | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 8

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the output of [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) to [`Get-Random -Count 4`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315402.aspx) to randomly select 4 of the folders.

Then you just need to do another [`ForEach`](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/) loop to go through each of the folders you selected.  You can get the full name of the file and the last write time by selecting the properties [`Fullname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) and [`lastwritetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx).

From there you will either need to create and array to get the data out of the `ForEach` loop, or create a file and write the information to it. If you go with the second option, I would recommend [`export-csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx) so you can easily add fields you want to track and read out the data into something more meaningful later on as requirements change.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\Documents and Settings\a528602\Desktop\Tools\Store Server\Servers.txt" 

Foreach($ServerName in $ServerList) 
{ 
    $Folders = get-childitem $ServerName -Directory | Get-Random -Count 4 | select Fullname
    ForEach ($Folder in $Fodlers) 
    {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder | Select Fullname,lastwritetime
    }
}
```

Edit: Added links to the commands used.